# Loop through object and show data where Y is present

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object that has a property called response, this contains a string with Y's and N's. The next property is details, the order of this is the same as response e.g the first Y is related to details.1 and the second N is related to details.2 etc. How can I loop through this object and show a paragraph and an image for only the details that have a corresponding Y.

```
var options = {
    response: "YNY",
    details: {
        1: {
            text: "This is the first option",
            img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        },
        2: {
            text: "This is the second option",
            img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        },
        3: {
           text: "This is the third option",
           img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        }
    }
};

var resp = options.response.split("");
var options = options.details;
```

Comment: `Object.keys(options.details).filter( (_, i) => options.response[i] === "Y" ).map(key => options.details[key])`

Comment: @destoryer can you explain it to me? what are e and i parameters? and how does response[i] take individual characters from the response string?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt `i` is the index of the array (when looping over object's keys) which can be used to access the `i`th element of the [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. `split('')` is fine. You can further loop through this array and create a string value for the HTML that you want to add to the page as `options.details[index+1]` and then create `p` and `img` tags which go into the page.

```js
var options = {
    response: "YNY",
    details: {
        1: {
            text: "This is the first option",
            img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        },
        2: {
            text: "This is the second option",
            img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        },
        3: {
           text: "This is the third option",
           img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        }
    }
};

var resp = options.response.split("");
var nHTML = '';
resp.forEach(function(character, index){
  if(character === 'Y'){
    nHTML+= '<p> '+options.details[index+1].text+'<img src="'+options.details[index+1].img+'"></p>';
  }
});
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = nHTML;
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the keys and filter the part array and map the values.

```js
var options = { response: "YNY", details: { 1: { text: "This is the first option", img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300" }, 2: { text: "This is the second option", img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300" }, 3: { text: "This is the third option", img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300" } } },
    resp = options.response.split(""),
    details = resp
        .map((s, i) => s === 'Y' && i + 1)
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(k => options.details[k]);
        
console.log(details);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over response string and check if it contains Y or N, if Y then get Image src and text

```js
var options = {
        response: "YNY",
        details: {
            1: {
                text: "This is the first option",
                img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
            },
            2: {
                text: "This is the second option",
                img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
            },
            3: {
               text: "This is the third option",
               img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
            }
        }
    };

    var resp = options.response;
    var options = options.details;
    var content="";

    for(var i=0;i<resp.length;i++)
     {
    if(resp[i]=="Y")
   {
    content += "<p>" + options[i+1].text+"<br><img src='"+options[i+1].img+"' width='400px' height='400px'/>";
   }
 
    }
   document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML = content ;
```

```html
<div id='divID'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```js
var options = {
    response: "YNY",
    details: {
        1: {
            text: "This is the first option",
            img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        },
        2: {
            text: "This is the second option",
            img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        },
        3: {
           text: "This is the third option",
           img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
        }
    }
};

var resp = options.response.split("");
Object.values(options.details).forEach(function(item, i){
  if(resp[i] === 'Y'){
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<p>' + item.text + '<br> '+' <img src=' + item.img+'/>';
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)** to loop over the `options.details` object values and filter them based on the corresponding character in `options.response`, using **[`Array#filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**.

This is how should be your code:

```
var results = Object.values(options.details).filter(function(d, i) {
  return options.response.split("")[i] == "Y";
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var options = {
  response: "YNY",
  details: {
    1: {
      text: "This is the first option",
      img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
    },
    2: {
      text: "This is the second option",
      img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
    },
    3: {
      text: "This is the third option",
      img: "http://www.placecage.com/200/300"
    }
  }
};

var results = Object.values(options.details).filter(function(d, i) {
  return options.response.split("")[i] == "Y";
});
console.log(results);
```

**ES6:**

```
var results = Object.values(options.details).filter((d, i) =>
  (options.response.split("")[i] == "Y")
);
```